# C What am i doing wrong in this code?

Tags: c

Hello i am new to C programming, i made a simple code that receives a string and capitalize only the first letter of each word and any other letter should be lower case and this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char k[30];
    printf("Please enter a sentece in capital letters: ");
    scanf("%s", k);
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        while (k[i] == ' ')
            i++;
        if (k[i] >= 'A' && k[i] <= 'Z')
            i++;
        while (k[i] >= 'A' && k[i] <= 'Z' && k[i] != ' ')
        {
            k[i] = k[i] + 32;
            i++;
        } // While loop
    } // For loop
    printf("%s", k);
} // main
```

The code only prints the first word(and stops without even printing the whole string) without converting any letter to lower case or capitalize the first letter, what am i doing wrong ?

EDIT:It seems i have overlooked the for loop and ,mixed '<' with '>' now that it has been fixed i ran the code and it printed the first word OK with proper capitalization but stopped after the first word and didn't print anything after that.

Comment: That's not C# code...

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: `for (int i=0;i>30;i++){` --> `for (int i=0;i<30;i++){`  . The entire `for` loop is getting skipped since `i` is initialized to 0, it's not >30.

Comment: Thank you very much @yano can't believe i overlooked that, now the code only prints the first word and skips everything else (first word is working fine with first letter capitalized and other letters lower case

Comment: Now it's time to take a debugger.

Comment: "You're entering a sentence like this" and it's only printing "You're"?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but 30 characters isn't much.. memory is cheap, change that to `char k[512];` or something. And you should probably use `fgets` instead so you don't risk overflowing your `k` buffer.

Comment: too much in the body of your `for` loop. All you need to do is look for a space, and if the character after that one is a small letter (and within the bounds of your buffer), change it to upper case; Otherwise, do nothing. I think just one `if` would do it. All the `i++` aren't necessary, that's what the `for` loop is going to do for you. If you want to do something like that, change them to `continue` statements. The very first letter of the input is a special case that I would handle outside of the loop.

Comment: Oh, heh,,, well I'm a bit surprised that change fixed everything. But if you overflow your buffer you invoke undefined behavior, and all bets are off after that.

Comment: I only started learning C just a week ago so I guess there is a lot to learn, thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, that code is no C#, is only c, I think that is the reason your code is not running.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that in line 6, you wrote `for (int i=0;i>30;i++)`. Notice how it says `i>30` instead of `i<30`, so this loop will not execute. Instead, write `for (int i=0;i<30;i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed by using `fgets` instead of `scanf` all thanks to @yano :)